# In Qt, how do I use Q_OBJECT slots and signals with multiple inheritance?

Tags: qt, qobject

I looked through the related questions and couldn't find anything that addresses exactly what I was talking about, so let me describe.

I have a class, let's say foo that needs to have its own slots and signals, but also needs to inherit from QXmlDefaultHandler (sounds rather odd, but I encountered this situation when trying to use QHttp to read a website directly into a QBuffer).

```
class foo: public QXmlDefaultHandler, public QObject
{
    public:
        foo();
        ~foo();

       Q_OBJECT
   public slots:
       void bar();
}
```

This code, if accompanied by a cpp to connect bar to a signal somewhere else, will not compile. You'll get errors about some members of QObject not being a member of QXmlDefaultHandler. Additionally, you can't move Q_OBJECT or else you get vtable errors for not implementing some things (go on! try it!).

please see my answer for the (very simple) fix. I will entertain voting you as the accepted answer if I think you explain it better than I do.

edit: for you c++ and Qt vets, please post an answer if you can explain it better. i spent quite a bit of time looking this info up, so please help someone else if you can do better than me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [documentation for moc](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/moc.html#multiple-inheritance-requires-qobject-to-be-first) states that in cases of multiple inheritance, the class providing QObject should appear first

> If you are using multiple inheritance,
>   moc assumes that the first inherited
>   class is a subclass of QObject. Also,
>   be sure that only the first inherited
>   class is a QObject.
>
> ```
>  // correct
>  class SomeClass : public QObject, public OtherClass
>  {
>      ...
>  };
> ```
>
> Virtual inheritance with QObject is
>   not supported.

Answer (score 2):

```
class foo: public QObject, public QXmlDefaultHandler
{
    public:
        foo();
        ~foo();
   Q_OBJECT
   public slots:
       void bar();
}
```

As simple as it sounds, if you don't put QObject first in the inheritance list, this task is impossible. It's a limitation in Qt's meta object system. If you don't do this, the compiler will try to apply some members of QObject as part of QXmlDefaultHandler.